# How to get text from this html page with jsoup?

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I am using this code to retreive the text in the main article on this page.

```
public class HtmlparserExampleActivity extends Activity {
String outputtext;
  TagFindingVisitor visitor;
  Parser parser = null;
private static final String TAG = "TVGuide";



TextView outputTextView;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    outputTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.outputTextView);
    String id = "main-article-content";
    Document doc = null;

    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect("http://movies.ign.com/articles/100/1002569p1.html").get();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Log.i("DOC", doc.toString().toString());
    Elements elementsHtml = doc.getElementsByTag(id);  
    String[] temp1 = new String[99];    
    int i =0;
    for(Element element: elementsHtml)
    {

        temp1[1] = element.text();
        i++;
        outputTextView.setText(temp1[1]);
```

The problem is nothing is showing up in the textview. None of the text that i am trying to retreive is showing up. The Log.i is showing up with the segments in the debug log. So i know its connecting successfully. Just dont know why im not getting any text in the textview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simplified extract of relevance from your question:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://movies.ign.com/articles/100/1002569p1.html").get();
Elements elementsHtml = doc.getElementsByTag("main-article-content");  
// ...
```

You're making a fundamental mistake here. There are no HTML tags like `<main-article-content>` in the document. However, there's a `<div id="main-article-content">`. According the CSS selector overview about halfway this [Jsoup cookbook](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax), you should be using `#id` selector.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://movies.ign.com/articles/100/1002569p1.html").get();
Element mainArticleContent = doc.select("#main-article-content").first();  
// ...
```

Comment: Thanks alot. What would you recommend me doing to learn about DOM, CSS to be more familiar with this?

Comment: Develop some websites with HTML and CSS (in a separate `.css` file!). The linked Jsoup cookbook overview is really all you need. For a more advanced overview see w3 http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html

Comment: Thanks for all the help. Im new to all of this.  sorry for the confusion.