# How to parse Text and Images from this

Tags: android, jsoup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get text from this html page with jsoup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016599/how-to-get-text-from-this-html-page-with-jsoup)

I am trying to parse the images and text from this HTML page using JSOUP.

http://movies.ign.com/articles/100/1002569p1.html

Here is the code i am trying to use to retreive it. But i get nothing returned into the TextView.

The "Doc" Log is logging things from the html page, so its connecting. Im just not receiving any text for some reason.

```
public class HtmlparserExampleActivity extends Activity {
String outputtext;
  TagFindingVisitor visitor;
  Parser parser = null;
private static final String TAG = "TVGuide";



TextView outputTextView;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    outputTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.outputTextView);
    String id = "main-article-content";
    Document doc = null;

    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect("http://movies.ign.com/articles/100/1002569p1.html").get();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Log.i("DOC", doc.toString().toString());
    Elements elementsHtml = doc.getElementsByTag(id);  
    String[] temp1 = new String[99];    
    int i =0;
    for(Element element: elementsHtml)
    {
        Log.i("data: ", element.text());
        temp1[1] = element.text();  
        outputTextView.setText(temp1[1]);
        i++;


    }




}
}
```

Comment: are you sure it's should be duo `toString().toString()`?

Comment: Its amazing that NOONE on here knows how to use jsoup!

Comment: That's not amazing. You just didn't use the `[jsoup]` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.May be your page is not loaded in doc before your code is executing

```
doc=Jsoup.parse(new URL("http://movies.ign.com/articles/100/1002569p1.html"),10000);
```

Comment: Still no luck..This is really fustrating